# C# ASP.NET API: setting MongoDb ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, api

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET API with MongoDb as my database, and I'm currently trying to insert JSON objects into my database. But for some reason I just can't set a custom ID for my database.

If I let MongoDb automatically generate an ID, there is no issue, I can simply put JSON objects into the database:

```
{"_id":"5db0b2cf6abcc72fa42c8991","id":"pand3d.8575483","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[108665.593,447232.925,0],[108667.648,447229.102,0],[108676.807,447234.217,0],[108674.334,447238.579,0],[108665.593,447232.925,0]]]},"geometry_name":"geovlak","properties":{"gid":8575483,"identificatie":"0513100011121832","aanduidingrecordinactief":false,"aanduidingrecordcorrectie":0,"officieel":false,"inonderzoek":false,"documentnummer":"BAGAV1776","documentdatum":"2018-08-15Z","bouwjaar":"1900-01-01Z","begindatumtijdvakgeldigheid":"2018-08-14T22:00:00Z","einddatumtijdvakgeldigheid":null,"gemeentecode":"0513","ground-000":"-0.44","ground-010":"-0.42","ground-020":"-0.41","ground-030":"-0.41","ground-040":"-0.4","ground-050":"-0.39","roof-025":"2.72","roof-050":"2.81","roof-075":"3.03","roof-090":"4.76","roof-095":"7.04","roof-099":"9.72","rmse-025":"0.87","rmse-050":"0.62","rmse-075":"0.62","rmse-090":"0.62","rmse-095":"0.62","rmse-099":"0.62","roof_flat":false,"nr_ground_pts":12,"nr_roof_pts":1247,"ahn_file_date":"2014-02-25T23:00:00Z","ahn_version":3,"height_valid":true,"tile_id":"38an2","bbox":["108665.593","447229.102","108676.807","447238.579"]}}
```

But as you can see, it generates a {"_id":"5db0b2cf6abcc72fa42c8991"} as the ID. But I want the {"id": "pand3d.8575483"} to act as ID.

So I made this Model:

```
 public class Bag3DMember
{
    [BsonId]
    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("geometry_name")]
    public string GeometryName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("properties")]
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }

}
```

But when I insert the JSON objects into the database, I get this error message:

**System.FormatException: 'Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class EnveoApi.Bag3DMember.'**

**Edit 1:**

So I changes my Model to:

```
   public class Bag3DMember
{
    [BsonId]
    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public string _Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("geometry_name")]
    public string GeometryName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("properties")]
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }

}
```

But still got the same error, with this stacktrace:

```
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)
```

at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize[TNominalType](IBsonReader bsonReader, Action`1 configurator)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize[TNominalType](String json, Action`1 configurator)
   at EnveoApi.Services.Bag3DService.SetupTestData() in D:\GitRepo\EnveoApi\Services\Bag3DService.cs:line 42
   at EnveoApi.Services.Bag3DService..ctor(IBag3DMemberDatabaseSettings settings) in D:\GitRepo\EnveoApi\Services\Bag3DService.cs:line 32
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

Comment: have you tried to refer to 'id' as '_id' instead?

Comment: I'm still getting System.FormatException: 'Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class EnveoApi.Bag3DMember.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I have a solution.

Thanks to barrypicker pointing out that my application was having difficulty deserialization instead of serialization, I figured it might be because:

Here, my JSON id property doesn't match my Model (with serialization)

```
[BsonId]
[DataMember]
[BsonElement("_id")]
public string _Id { get; set; }
```

But here, my id JSON property does match my model. But when MongoDb inserts it, it renames the ID to _id, which means my Model also doesn't match (with Deserializiation)

```
 [BsonId]
[DataMember]
[BsonElement("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

So tldr: I wrote a function that changes the JSON key "id" to "_id" before inserting.
Thanks barrypicker!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following and reply...

```
public class Bag3DMember
{
    [BsonId]
    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public string _Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("geometry_name")]
    public string GeometryName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("properties")]
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }

}
```

In your code, change references to `Bag3DMember.id` to `Bag3DMember._id`

Comment: I'm still getting **System.FormatException: 'Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class EnveoApi.Bag3DMember.'**

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you applied the code change?  There should be no element called 'id' now...    Specially look at `[BsonElemement("_id")]`

Comment: can you provide the stack trace and full error message?

Comment: Looking at the stack trace it is having difficulty with Deserialization, not serialization.  I believe this means it is trying to map an existing database document to your model but having problems.  Assuming this is a development database and the data doesn't really matter, please remove all field 'id' values from all (database) documents and try again. (or purge the database and try inserts and reads with the model changes).

Comment: I deleted the collection in my database an tried it again. Still the same error. For your information. I have a JSON file as test data, from which I insert it into the database. This is an example of a JSON object: https://pastebin.com/A6qEyNae

Comment: @Martijn - thanks, that helps.  I think the existence of field 'id' is causing problems.  The JSON file import created this field again.  In your sample JSON could you please rename to '_id' instead?  This means you will need to purge again and reload

Comment: Hi barrypicker, I just posted an answer based on your comment above. Thanks for  your help!